# unique_ptr does not call the destructor to free the pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

I am passing unique_ptr to function and then move the pointer to another unique_ptr, all is working fine as need, but while point is unique_ptr does not call destructor of the when it goes out of scope.

Below is my code. and its output, the code is in eclipse.

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class BaseCcExpander;
class DeriveHandler;
class ExpansionRuleExecuter;
class DeriveType1;

class ParamBase
{
public :

    ParamBase()
    {
        std::cout << "Ctor:ParamBase:\n";
    }
    std::unique_ptr<ExpansionRuleExecuter> paramexpander;
    virtual ~ParamBase()     { std::cout << "Dtor::~ParamBase:\n"; }
    virtual void attachBase(int paramGrp,int paramId,std::unique_ptr<ExpansionRuleExecuter> xbaseExpander);

};

ParamBase* obj;
void ParamBase::attachBase(int paramGrp,int paramId,std::unique_ptr<ExpansionRuleExecuter> xbaseExpander)
{
    std::cout << "In:  ParamBase::attachHandler :\n";
    paramexpander = std::move(xbaseExpander);
}

class ExpansionRuleExecuter
{
public:
    ExpansionRuleExecuter()
    {
        std::cout << "Ctor ExpansionRuleExecuter::ExpansionRuleExecuter:\n" << endl;
    }
    virtual ~ExpansionRuleExecuter(){

        std::cout << "Dtor ~ExpansionRuleExecuter::ExpansionRuleExecuter:\n" << endl;
    }
    virtual void handleExpansion() = 0;

};
class DeriveHandler : public ExpansionRuleExecuter
{
public:
    DeriveHandler()
    {
        std::cout << "Ctor::DeriveHandler:\n" << endl;
    }

     ~DeriveHandler()
    {
        std::cout << "Dtor::~DeriveHandler:\n" << endl;
    }

     void handleExpansion()
     {
         std::cout << "DeriveHandler expanded\n" << endl;
     }
};



ParamBase *obj1;
class BaseCcExpander
{
public:
    BaseCcExpander()
    {
        std::cout << "Ctor::BaseCcExpander:\n" << endl;
    }

    virtual ~BaseCcExpander()
    {
        std::cout << "Dtor::~BaseCcExpander:\n" << endl;
    }

    typedef unique_ptr<ExpansionRuleExecuter> ccHandler;
    BaseCcExpander::ccHandler ccBaseHandler;

    void attachHandler(int paramGrp, int paramId,std::unique_ptr<ExpansionRuleExecuter> xhandler)
    {
        std::cout << "BaseCcExpander::attachHandler:\n" << endl;
        obj1->attachBase(paramGrp,paramId,std::move(xhandler));
    }

};


class DeriveType1 : public ParamBase
{
public :
    DeriveType1()      { std::cout << "Ctor: DeriveType--------1:\n"  << endl;}
    ~DeriveType1()     { std::cout << "Dtor::~DeriveType---------1\n" << endl;}
    void attachBase(std::unique_ptr<ExpansionRuleExecuter> xbaseExpander);
};

BaseCcExpander ccexpander;


int main()
{

    obj1 = new(DeriveType1);
    ccexpander.attachHandler(1,2,std::unique_ptr<ExpansionRuleExecuter>(new DeriveHandler));
    if(obj1->paramexpander.get())
    {
        ExpansionRuleExecuter *expand = obj1->paramexpander.get();
        expand->handleExpansion();
    }
}
```

Comment: Objects allocated with `new` must be destroyed and deallocated using `delete`.

Comment: but the new is been allocated to unique_ptr, so its the job of unique_ptr to delete the allocation.

Comment: The `unique_ptr` in question is a member of `*obj1`, and would be destroyed when the latter is destroyed - but `*obj1` is never destroyed: your program leaks it.

Comment: but by is obj1 not destroying even after the program is over as its in the global space, it should destroy

Comment: The OS will clean up your memory leak (if the OS supports that, not every OS does), but the OS will not call any destructors in your program. The OS sees a chunk of memory allocated by the program, and just releases it for use by other processes. When the OS releases the memory for a process, that process has stopped running, as the destructors are a part of you running code, these will not be run.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote in a comment:

> but by is `obj1` not destroying even after the program is over as its in the global space, it should destroy.

There is some misunderstanding here. `obj1` is destroyed but the object it points to is not deleted when `obj1` is destroyed. If the compiler did that, you won't be able to use:

```
int main()
{
   int i = 10;
   int* ip = &i;
   // You don't want the run time to call the equivalent of
   // delete ip;
   // when the function returns. That will lead to undefined behavior
   // since ip does not point to memory allocated from the heap.
}
```

When the program ends, the OS reclaims the memory used by the program but that does not mean that it calls the destructor of `obj1`.

Had the destructor been responsible for releasing resources other than memory, such as network connections, locks on shared files/folders, etc., they will not be released when the program ends without the destructor getting called.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable pointed by `obj1` is not `delete`d, hence its members would not be destroyed until the `delete` happens and the `unique_ptr` will remain alive then the destructor will never be called.

You should either call `delete` on `obj1` at the end of your program or use an `unique_ptr` on it.

Comment: While you are right about the error (and I like the suggestion to use a unique_ptr for the allocated object), your wording is a bit fuzzy: "Your variable obj1 is not deleted" is, strictly spoken, false. `obj1` is deleted alright when main() returns, which is exactly why using a local unique_ptr would work. It's the *object pointed to* by `obj1`, i.e., as Igor put it in a comment, `*obj1` which doesn't get `delete`d.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider yes you are right, I will correct this rightaway